# Tradingview Pinescript Percentage Return

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm backtesting a strategy in pinescript and I want to plot the percentage returns rather than the dollar amount of equity. If I use `plot(strategy.equity)`, it plots the dollar amount. If I use `plot(strategy.percent_of_equity)` I get an error stating

`line 45: Cannot call 'plot' with 'series'=const string. The argument should be of type: series[float]`

Essentially I want to see a percentage here rather than the dollar amount:

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**strategy.percent_of_equity** is an **ENUM** supouse to use in strategy tag

```
//version=5
strategy(title,shorttitle,default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
```

**to show PnL in percentage**

```
chg             = strategy.equity - strategy.initial_capital // equity now - equity start
earn_percent    = strategy.initial_capital*(chg*0.01) //turn change to percentage, add it on equity start

plot(earn_percent,"Live PnL in %" , color=color.lime)
```